# Does iOS support BC4 compressed texture?

Tags: textures, ios, opengl-es, compression

I've been designing a new OpenGL image algorithm using BC4 textures at its core.
It works well accross Windows and Mac, my main targets up to now.

But today, the customer added a new requirement : it should work on iOS too !
I'm starting to worry : is BC4 texture (named GL_COMPRESSED_RED_RGTC1 in OpenGL) supported on iOS devices (tablets & iphones alike) ?

I've read that iOS is OpenGL ES 2.0 capable. But i'm unable to know which textures are supported under this API (except PowerVR ones, which are not compatible with PC & Macs...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i guess i have to answer my own question.
I have not found a single compressed texture format in common between iOS and PC/Mac.
Apparently, the only type of compressed textures supported by iOS are PowerVR-based, which are completely proprietary (e.g. not part of OpenGL standard).

So I guess my question is included in this answer : iOS does not support BC4 textures.